# Charts McRouter - How to amend the memcache resources like memory and cpu

Tags: charts, memcached, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

Have set-up mcrouter using helm charts on Google Kubernetes Engine, however failing to find a way to either amend the memcached resources / set them while deploying the mcrouter especially for memcached. The default resources set for memory (64MB) and cpu (50m) and these are too low?

Followed the instructions from below:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-memcached-on-kubernetes-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could set the memory / cpu, while installing the mcrouter using helm:

helm install stable/mcrouter --name=memcache--set memcached.replicaCount=2 --set memcached.resources.requests.memory=256Mi